# build heatmap with cesiun,there always disappear when basemap fresh

Tags: heatmap, cesiumjs

I want to add heatmap on map. This is my code:

```
var mycanvas = document.getElementsByClassName('heatmap-canvas')
var imgData = mycanvas[1].toDataURL('image/png')
viewer.entities.add({
        name: 'heatmap',
        rectangle: new Cesium.RectangleGraphics({
            coordinates: Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(108.91125287994653, 34.16562697211902, 
                                                      108.92125287994653, 34.17562697211902),
            material: new Cesium.ImageMaterialProperty({
                image: imgData,
                // image: './favicon.ico',
                transparent: true
            })
            // material: Cesium.Color.BLUE.withAlpha(0.5)
        })

    })
}
```

The first look is ok. But when zoomed in, the heat map will disappear. It's so strange.

Thank you for your help.

```
Map
```

[image]

```
Map (Zoomed)
```

[image]